# jquery: get elements by class name and add css to each of them

Tags: jquery, class

I have a certain number of div boxes that all have the same class name. I am trying to apply something to them all but have no luck. The code I constructed so far is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    elements = $('div.easy_editor');
    elements.each(function() { $(this).css("border","9px solid red"); });
    //elements[0].css("border","9px solid red");
});
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: The code is not too elegant, but right.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can try this

```
 $('div.easy_editor').css({'border-width':'9px', 'border-style':'solid', 'border-color':'red'});
```

The `$('div.easy_editor')` refers to a collection of all divs that have the class easy editor already. There is no need to use each() unless there was some function that you wanted to run on each. The css() method actually applies to all the divs you find.

Comment: Thanks that worked! The real source of pronlem was (silly silly me) that I created boxes as spans but in jQuery was trying to access them as divs *facepalm*

Answer (score 7):

What makes jQuery easy to use is that you don't have to apply attributes to each element. The jQuery object contains an array of elements, and the methods of the jQuery object applies the same attributes to all the elements in the array.

There is also a shorter form for `$(document).ready(function(){...})` in `$(function(){...})`.

So, this is all you need:

```
$(function(){
  $('div.easy_editor').css('border','9px solid red');
});
```

If you want the code to work for any element with that class, you can just specify the class in the selector without the tag name:

```
$(function(){
  $('.easy_editor').css('border','9px solid red');
});
```